# Fusing soul shields into Moonwater Arena soul shields

Tags: blade-and-soul

I have a few cinderlands critical soulshield primer (obtained from crafting with Soul Wardens) but I am not able to use these to fuse into Moonwater Arena soulshields. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fuse soul shields the following requirements need to be met:

1. They need to be the same quality(or lower than the one you're fusing them into)
2. Different sets
3. And they need to be from the same zone

Since your soul shields are not from the same zone, you won't be able to fuse them.